# RecyclerView lags when I use the scrollbar when there is a large amount of data

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

**My RecyclerAdapter**

```
public class CollatzAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CollatzAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    List<Long> primeList;

    public CollatzAdapter() {
    }

    public CollatzAdapter(ArrayList<BigInteger> list, ArrayList<Long> primeList) {
        this.list = list;
        this.primeList = primeList;
    }
    public CollatzAdapter(ArrayList<BigInteger> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CollatzAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CollatzAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mIterationPosition.setText((position + ":"));
        holder.mNumber.setText(list.get(position).toString());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mNumber;
        public TextView mIterationPosition;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iteration_num);
            mIterationPosition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iteration_position);
            //mPrime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iteration_prime);
        }

    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<BigInteger> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

**Where I Implement**

```java
iterationFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_iteration, container, false);
    collatzViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(CollatzViewModel.class);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) iterationFragment.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mAdapter = new CollatzAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    collatzViewModel.getCollatz().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),(list)->{
        mAdapter.setList(list);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```

When `RecyclerView` contains large `BigIntegers`, say 300 characters for one integer and a list 100,000 of them, it lags when I use the scrollbar. Is there a way to prevent it from lagging when I scroll? It lags so much that it crashes the app. I don't understand why this happens since the `RecyclerView` should only load a couple of `BigIntegers`.

Repository: https://github.com/ErickSorto/Collatz-Calculator

Comment: It's not as much issue of recyclerview as it is performance of `BigInteger.toString()`, when you scroll you invoke it for every view that appears but apparently stringifying 300+ digit integers is too expensive to be done per-frame. You'll need to lazily (and asynchronously?) load strings for each item as it appears.

Comment: How would I approach this?  Do you think having all the data in the array as strings already would make it faster?

Comment: Have you tried remove the notifyDataSetChanged() from your Fragment and move it to inside your method setList in Adapter?

Comment: @WallaceBaldenebre Hey I just tried it, and it still lagged and crashed the app. I put this.notifyDataSetChanged() in method setList